# docker compose run commands on the containers without a dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am wondering if its possible to install dependancies in the containers without creating aditional dockerfiles.

Basic example is php apache + mysqli.

For mysqli I need to run:

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli && apachectl restart
```

But I dont want to create a seperate file just to run this command.

I have tried adding it as a command to the docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  apache-php:
    image: php:8.1-apache
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    command: docker-php-ext-install mysqli && apachectl restart
    ports:
      - "5520:80"
```

The commands succesfully execute but then the container shuts down.
As soon as I add any command even if its `echo "hello"` the container will shutdown.
Ive read so much of the documentation and I cant see a clear reason for this or hunt down any way to make the container stay open.

Ive read a lot of stack overflows on using sleep, tty interactive and other tricks to keep the container from shutting down but none of them work.

I can acheive a single file setup with simple bash script using docker cli:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Use the project folder as the prefix for our containers and networks.
PROJECT=`basename $(pwd)`

# HTTP: APACHE + PHP + MYSQLI
NAME="${PROJECT}_http"
PORT="5520"
docker run -dit --name "$NAME" -p $PORT:80 \
  -v `pwd`:/var/www/html \
  php:8.1-apache

docker exec "$NAME" docker-php-ext-install mysqli
docker exec "$NAME" apachectl restart
```

This script works fine, and I can also do anything I want (create networks aliases etc) with docker cli but docker-compose would be nicer.

I just dont want to create a bunch of extra files for some simple commands to run. Surely there is a way?

If its not possible I guess I just keep expanding the bash script and build my network that way.

Comment: Why are you not just creating a Dockerfile to build a custom image with the appropriate configuration?

Comment: No good reason really. Just dont want to create extra files and folders if I can use a single file Id rather do it that way.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that's a bad idea: you'll end up with a much more manageable configuration if you isolate the configuration for each image into it's own Dockerfile. Trying to configure everything *after* the container is running will make it more difficult to share your work with others, and I think you may may find yourself fighting the design of some existing images if you try doing things this way. Ultimately, it's up to you, but by not following best practices I think you'll make your life more difficult.

Comment: Noted, and I expected that kind of response. But I gotta scratch this itch lol. With a dockerfile Its still being run after the container is created. The only difference is that its in a different file with more lines of configuration needed in both files. Just seems  unnessisary and if there is a command option for the yaml, why does it not work?